# JavaFX datepicker - how to update date in a second datepicker object?

Tags: javafx, datepicker

Problem:
I've two datepicker object checkIn_date and checkOut_date in the same scene.
There is a way to change automatically the date field in the second datepicker object?
For example : checkIn_date is set with 2015-08-10 and checkOut_date is set with 2015-08-11. If I change the date field in checkIn_date i.e. 2015-08-22, checkOut_date update automatically to 2015-08-23.
Thanks for any advices.

Comment: From the help center: 'Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).' Can you clarify what you expect to happen, what does (or doesn't happen), and create an MCVE?

Comment: Thanks James_D for your suggestion. I've changed the question. I hope this will help.

Comment: Why did you remove your code?

Comment: Because doesn't express the real problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a listener to your `check-in DatePicker`, fetch the new value, add the no of days you want to it and update the new value to the `check-out DatePicker`.

Here is a MCVE to give more idea on what I meant :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private final int noOfDaysToAdd = 2;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Label checkInLabel = new Label("Check In :    ");
        Label checkOutLabel = new Label("Check Out : ");
        DatePicker picker1 = new DatePicker();
        DatePicker picker2 = new DatePicker();

        // Listener for updating the checkout date w.r.t check in date
        picker1.valueProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            picker2.setValue(newValue.plusDays(noOfDaysToAdd));
        });

        HBox checkInBox = new HBox(10, checkInLabel, picker1);
        HBox checkOutBox = new HBox(10, checkOutLabel, picker2);
        checkInBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        checkOutBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        root.getChildren().addAll(checkInBox, checkOutBox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Update**

You can re-write the snippet

```
picker1.valueProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    picker2.setValue(newValue.plusDays(noOfDaysToAdd));
});
```

without the lambda as :

```
picker1.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<LocalDate>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends LocalDate> observable, LocalDate oldValue, LocalDate newValue) {
        picker2.setValue(newValue.plusDays(noOfDaysToAdd));
    }
});
```

Comment: What does it mean, ov in parameter list (ov, oldValue, newValue)?

Comment: `ov` is the `ObservableValue`. I have used lambda to remove the anonymous class `ChangeListener`. Updated the answer for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

First thanks for the help!
I've fixed my problem from another point of view.
When scene/view has been loaded either datepicker are set to current date for check-in and the day after the curent day for check-out date.
For check-in day I've disabled the selection of days before the current date and after check-out date.
For check-out day I've disabled the selection of days before check-out date.

Unfortunately I can't post any image because my reputation is not 10!

But this is the code for the controller class:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import com.main.controller.checker.DateChecker;
import com.main.controller.datautil.DataFetch;
import com.main.controller.datautil.DataStore;
import com.main.controller.util.Initilizable;

public class SearchCtrl implements Initilizable{

@FXML
private DatePicker check_in;

@FXML
private DatePicker check_out;

@Override
public void init() {        
    check_in.setValue(LocalDate.now());
    check_out.setValue(check_in.getValue().plusDays(1));
    DateChecker.setBeginDateBounds(check_in, check_out.getValue());
    DateChecker.setEndDateBounds(check_out, check_in.getValue());
    check_in.setOnAction( (event) ->   {DateChecker.setEndDateBounds(check_out, check_in.getValue());});
    datafine.setOnAction( (event) -> {DateChecker.setBeginDateBounds(check_in, check_out.getValue());});
}
```

This is the DateChecker class:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import javafx.scene.control.DateCell;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class DateChecker {

private DateChecker(){
}

public static void setBeginDateBounds(DatePicker begin_date, LocalDate end_date ){
    final Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {

        @Override
        public DateCell call(final DatePicker datePicker) {
            return new DateCell() {

                @Override
                public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    boolean cond = (item.isBefore(LocalDate.now()) || !item.isBefore(end_date));
                    if (cond){
                        setDisable(true);
                        setStyle("-fx-background-color: #d3d3d3;");
                    }else{
                        setDisable(false);
                        setStyle("-fx-background-color: #CCFFFF;");
                        setStyle("-fx-font-fill: black;");
                    }
                }
            };
        }   
    };
    begin_date.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory);       
}

public static void setEndDateBounds(DatePicker end_date, LocalDate begin_date ){
    final Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {

        @Override
        public DateCell call(final DatePicker datePicker) {
            return new DateCell() {

                @Override
                public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    boolean cond = (item.isBefore(LocalDate.now()) || !item.isAfter(begin_date));
                    if (cond){
                        setDisable(true);
                        setStyle("-fx-background-color: #d3d3d3;");
                    }else{
                        setDisable(false);
                        setStyle("-fx-background-color: #CCFFFF;");
                        setStyle("-fx-font-fill: black;");
                    }
                }
            };
        }   
    };
    end_date.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory);     
 }
}
```

I hope this will help!