# JavaFX DatePicker listener to filter data in TableView

Tags: javafx, datepicker, tableview

In the simplest way to put it, I want to filter data in a TableView based on the date range from the selected dates in two DatePickers.

Is there a way to add a listener or something similar to that of using addListener on TextFields or is there a better way to go about this? I can't find any tutorial explaining this.

Should I just aim for calling a Postgres view to update the table when a button is pressed?

In the image, if it were working it would show just the rows with TID 16 and 17, where the date in "Opened" column is between the date range.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460059/javafx-datepicker-how-to-update-date-in-a-second-datepicker-object

Comment: You want to add a listener to the second `DatePicker`. Check to make sure the second date is later than the first. Next, filter the table based on the date range. I would peronsally  use a `FilteredList` on the `TableView`. http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/

Comment: @Sedrick Thanks, I had the date constraint already and the listener part I tried to apply to the dates using the filteredList but found much more complicated with all the formats than what I came up with using a function that calls a view where the results are between those dates.

Comment: @EstebanRodriguez Usually creating a `Predicate` based on 2 `LocalDate`s shouldn't be hard. Are you using `java.sql.Date` in your item class or why do you consider this complicated?

Comment: @fabian Maybe it's not so bad, but with my limited time to get this done and basically the formatting between dates is what got me, but now that I look back on it seems that I did understand the date formatting but the comparison between dates. Should I have went with comparing strings instead? I wish I still had the code, but it's basically what Sedrick linked in the first comment except I couldn't get the comparison parts for dates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following answer I assume you use `LocalDate` in your item class. If you use `java.sql.Date` the following question explains how to do a conversion:

[Convert between LocalDate and sql.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750861/convert-between-localdate-and-sql-date)

Use `FilteredList` to filter the complete data set (assuming the db table is small enough to store it in the client's memory).

```
ObservableList<TableItem> allItems = ...
FilteredList<TableItem> filteredItems = new FilteredList<>(allItems);

// bind predicate based on datepicker choices
filteredItems.predicateProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
        LocalDate minDate = startPicker.getValue();
        LocalDate maxDate = endPicker.getValue();

        // get final values != null
        final LocalDate finalMin = minDate == null ? LocalDate.MIN : minDate;
        final LocalDate finalMax = maxDate == null ? LocalDate.MAX : maxDate;

        // values for openDate need to be in the interval [finalMin, finalMax]
        return ti -> !finalMin.isAfter(ti.getOpenDate()) && !finalMax.isBefore(ti.getOpenDate());
    },
    startPicker.valueProperty(),
    endPicker.valueProperty()));

tableView.setItems(filteredItems);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. It's easy to follow. What I had before wasn't close this. I am using LocalDate in my class. That's what I found online for data for equivalence. Would formatting the date in the class affect the comparison when using this filtered list?

Comment: In case anyone wants a filtered query too, just create another FilteredList2 below this FilteredList1 and set the input as FilteredList1. Set new predicateProperty to FilteredList2 and set conditions as required. This will filter out query of specified date. Advantage? Even if date is null, you can still get filtered data based on query.